# addEventListener paste event firing multiple times

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect paste action in Chrome. Here's my code:

```
document.addEventListener("paste",function(e){
    console.log('pasted')
})
```

It can detect paste action, however firing multiple times

[image]

sometimes twice, sometime 3 or more times...
And when I paste multiple times, the fire times just add based on previous numbers.

**eg:**

```
first paste -- fire 3 times  
second paste -- fire 5 times  
third paste -- fire 8 times...
```

Is anyone knows the reason and how to let it only fire once at a time? Thanks!

Comment: We can't help you without a [mcve], but if you're getting the callback multiple times, it's because your code adding the event listener (the code you've quoted in the question) is being run multiple times. Make sure it's only run once, and you'll only get one callback.

Comment: Is it possible that your listener is being added more than once?

Comment: Have you tried adding the EventListener to input element directly once?

Comment: @Take_Care_ I am building a rich text editor using slate and want to detect when user paste something in to the document. I tried window.addEventListener, still fire multiple times.

Comment: Like Fibonacci (..;3;5;8;..) sequence? strange!

Comment: So, user can edit on the whole page like a canvas?